# Add multiple property method to a graphtraversal object in a loop statement

Tags: gremlin, gremlin-server

Is there a way to add multi property methods to a graphtraversal object at runtime, in a loop statement?
I have tried the following but it did not work!

```
        while ((currentDataLine = nodeBufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            //split graph data
            data = currentDataLine.split(DELIMITER);

            for (int i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (i == 15) continue;
                if (data[i].isEmpty() || data[i] == "") continue;
                graphTraversal.V(data[15]).property(header[i], data[i]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

By calling `graphTraversal.V()` normally written as `g.V()` you are creating a new `Traversal` object on every iteration of your loop. Just instantiate the `Traversal` outside of the `for` loop and then go from there:

```
    while ((currentDataLine = nodeBufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        //split graph data
        data = currentDataLine.split(DELIMITER);

        Traversal t = g.V(data[15]);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (i == 15) continue;
            if (data[i].isEmpty() || data[i] == "") continue;
            t = t.property(header[i], data[i]);
        }

        // remember to actually execute your Traversal - that doesn't happen
        // until you next(), iterate(), etc.
        t.iterate()
    }
```